# Use javascript to create hyperlink from html5 details summary data element

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using details and summary from HTML5. I want to have a list of professions. When the user opens the summary item for a paritcular professional it renders a hyperlink to a page with the functional skill requirements for that profession. The document code for this page (example 47-2061.00) is stored in the data element for each summary element.
How can I use the data element from the summary tag to write a hyperlink (e.g. https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/) with the information appended to the end?

I believe I need to use a for loop for a foreach to attach a listener to each summary tag using document.getElementsByTagName but I could give them a class and do it via getElementsByClassName

Then I'm not sure what I need to do next.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/BazVQKz?editors=1111)

```js
//https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/



var userSelection = document.getElementsByTagName("summary");

for (let i = 0; i < userSelection.length; i++) {
  userSelection[i].addEventListener("toggle", function() {
    console.log("Added listener " + i);
  })
}

var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("functional skills");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "functional skills";
a.href = "https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/";
/*the above needs to append the data attribute from the summary item clicked for example https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/53-7064.00*/
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

```html
<details id="agriculture" class="details">
  <summary>Agriculture</summary>
  <details>
    <summary data="53-7064.00">Picking & packing</summary>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary data="45-2092.02">Farm worker</summary>
  </details>

  <details>
    <summary data="45-2091.00">Agricultural Equipment Operator</summary>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary data="45-2093.00">Farmworkers, Farm, Ranch, and Aquacultural Animals</summary>
  </details>

</details>

<details id="construction" class="details">
  <summary>Construction</summary>
  <details>
    <summary data="47-2061.00">Construction Labourer</summary>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary data="47-2073.00">Operating Engineers and Other Construction Equipment Operators</summary>
  </details>
  <details data="47-2051.00">
    <summary>Cement Masons and Concrete Finishers</summary>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary data="47-2021.00">Brickmasons and Blockmasons</summary>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary data="47-4031.00">Fence Erector</summary>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary data="17-3031.01">Surveying Technician</summary>
  </details>
</details>
```

Comment: Use `data-code` so you can read it from JavaScript with `<node>.dataset.code`

Comment: I have updated that in the codepen. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delegate:

```js
const root = "https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/"

const fs = document.createElement('a');
fs.id="FS";
const linkText = document.createTextNode("functional skills");
fs.appendChild(linkText);
fs.classList.add("hide");
fs.title = "functional skills";
document.body.appendChild(fs);


document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const isSummary = tgt.tagName==="SUMMARY";
  const code = tgt.dataset.code;
  fs.classList.toggle("hide",!isSummary || !code); // show only if summary AND code exists
  if (isSummary && code) {
    fs.href=root+code;
  }  
})
```

```css
.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <details id="agriculture" class="details">
    <summary>Agriculture</summary>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="53-7064.00">Picking & packing</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="45-2092.02">Farm worker</summary>
    </details>

    <details>
      <summary data-code="45-2091.00">Agricultural Equipment Operator</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="45-2093.00">Farmworkers, Farm, Ranch, and Aquacultural Animals</summary>
    </details>

  </details>

  <details id="construction" class="details">
    <summary>Construction</summary>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="47-2061.00">Construction Labourer</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="47-2073.00">Operating Engineers and Other Construction Equipment Operators</summary>
    </details>
    <details data-code="47-2051.00">
      <summary>Cement Masons and Concrete Finishers</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="47-2021.00">Brickmasons and Blockmasons</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="47-4031.00">Fence Erector</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="17-3031.01">Surveying Technician</summary>
    </details>
  </details>
</div>
```

Comment: I just had to make 1 tiny change but it's working. Thank you.
https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/WNxyReJ

Comment: Very impressive coding skills. Thank you.